# Need to delete a child and place the deleted child with same level as parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am looking for a XSLT code to delete a child and place the deleted child with same level as parent. Please find the below input :

```
<PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
        <personIdExternal>employee1</personIdExternal>
        <dateOfBirth>1995-05-01T00:00:00.000</dateOfBirth>
        <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <serviceDate/>
                <assignmentClass>GA</assignmentClass>
                <personIdExternal>employee1</personIdExternal>
                <empGlobalAssignmentNav>
                    <EmpGlobalAssignment>
                        <BenefitEnrollment>
                            <effectiveEndDate>2023-06-18T00:00:00.000</effectiveEndDate>
                            <workerId>90000028</workerId>
                        </BenefitEnrollment>
                        <BenefitEnrollment>
                            <effectiveEndDate>2023-06-19T00:00:00.000</effectiveEndDate>
                            <workerId>90000028</workerId>
                            <id>1213CF8537BE4248BE3231A0E4E7226F</id>
                        </BenefitEnrollment>
                            <id>1213CF8537BE4248BE3231A0E4E7226F</id>
                        <assignmentType>131144</assignmentType>
                        <startDate>2023-05-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
                    </EmpGlobalAssignment>
                </empGlobalAssignmentNav>
                <userId>employee1</userId>
                <startDate>2023-05-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
            </EmpEmployment>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <serviceDate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</serviceDate>
                <assignmentClass>ST</assignmentClass>
                <personIdExternal>employee1</personIdExternal>
                <empGlobalAssignmentNav/>
                <userId>employee1</userId>
                <startDate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </employmentNav>
    </PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
        <personIdExternal>employee2</personIdExternal>
        <dateOfBirth>1988-05-03T00:00:00.000</dateOfBirth>
        <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <serviceDate>2022-01-01T00:00:00.000</serviceDate>
                <assignmentClass>ST</assignmentClass>
                <personIdExternal>employee2</personIdExternal>
                <BenefitEnrollment>
                    <effectiveEndDate>2023-06-19T00:00:00.000</effectiveEndDate>
                    <workerId>employee2</workerId>
                    <id>45B130BDB62D476CB4A95B776BD59B8C</id>
                </BenefitEnrollment>
                <BenefitEnrollment>
                    <id>45B130BDB62D476CB4A95B776BD59B8C</id>
                </BenefitEnrollment>
                <empGlobalAssignmentNav/>
                <userId>employee2</userId>
                <startDate>2022-01-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </employmentNav>
    </PerPerson>
</PerPerson>
```

Here for the 1st person i.e employee1 the benefitenrollment child is under empGlobalAssignmentNav parent , the empGlobalAssignmentNav parent occurs only for global employees , so that means it may not come always

[image]

For the 2nd person i.e employee2 the benefitenrollment child is under empemployment parent .This case is for a local employee.

[image]

I would like to have the output as below . When ever there are benefitenrollments under empGlobalAssignmentNav ie employee 1, I would like those generated at parent level i.e under EmpEmployment , I dont want any change for Employee 2 , as employee 2 is already generating under EmpEmployment.

```
<PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
        <personIdExternal>employee1</personIdExternal>
        <dateOfBirth>1995-05-01T00:00:00.000</dateOfBirth>
        <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <serviceDate/>
                <assignmentClass>GA</assignmentClass>
                <personIdExternal>employee1</personIdExternal>
                <BenefitEnrollment>
                    <effectiveEndDate>2023-06-18T00:00:00.000</effectiveEndDate>
                    <workerId>90000028</workerId>
                </BenefitEnrollment>
                <BenefitEnrollment>
                    <effectiveEndDate>2023-06-19T00:00:00.000</effectiveEndDate>
                    <workerId>90000028</workerId>
                    <id>1213CF8537BE4248BE3231A0E4E7226F</id>
                </BenefitEnrollment>
                <empGlobalAssignmentNav>
                    <EmpGlobalAssignment>
                        <id>1213CF8537BE4248BE3231A0E4E7226F</id>
                        <assignmentType>131144</assignmentType>
                        <startDate>2023-05-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
                    </EmpGlobalAssignment>
                </empGlobalAssignmentNav>
                <userId>employee1</userId>
                <startDate>2023-05-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
            </EmpEmployment>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <serviceDate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</serviceDate>
                <assignmentClass>ST</assignmentClass>
                <personIdExternal>employee1</personIdExternal>
                <empGlobalAssignmentNav/>
                <userId>employee1</userId>
                <startDate>2023-01-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </employmentNav>
    </PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
        <personIdExternal>employee2</personIdExternal>
        <dateOfBirth>1988-05-03T00:00:00.000</dateOfBirth>
        <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <serviceDate>2022-01-01T00:00:00.000</serviceDate>
                <assignmentClass>ST</assignmentClass>
                <personIdExternal>employee2</personIdExternal>
                <BenefitEnrollment>
                    <effectiveEndDate>2023-06-19T00:00:00.000</effectiveEndDate>
                    <workerId>employee2</workerId>
                    <id>45B130BDB62D476CB4A95B776BD59B8C</id>
                </BenefitEnrollment>
                <BenefitEnrollment>
                    <id>45B130BDB62D476CB4A95B776BD59B8C</id>
                </BenefitEnrollment>
                <empGlobalAssignmentNav/>
                <userId>employee2</userId>
                <startDate>2022-01-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </employmentNav>
    </PerPerson>
</PerPerson>
```

[image]
I have tried the XSLT with the below logic, but no luck it is deleting the benefitenrolment child node segment from the empGlobalAssignmentNav and not placing under EmpEmployment

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="EmpEmployment">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="../empGlobalAssignmentNav/EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="empGlobalAssignmentNav/EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, but you have a few issues with your XSLT attempt and they all have to do with this line:

```xml
<xsl:apply-templates select="../empGlobalAssignmentNav/EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment"/>
```

1. The current context is `EmpEmployment` (because that's what the template matches and nothing changes that). `empGlobalAssignmentNav` is a child of `EmpEmployment` so when you start your select with `../` that goes up to the parent of `EmpEmployment` and it doesn't have a `EmpGlobalAssignmentNav` child. Remove the `../` from the select.
2. You have a template that removes the original `BenefitEnrollment` (`match="empGlobalAssignmentNav/EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment"`) which is correct but when you do the `apply-templates` that template also matches the `BenefitEnrollment` (because all matches are based on the input XML; not what you've changed in the output). You can simply change `apply-templates` to `copy-of` if you don't have any additional processing to do on those elements. Alternately you can use a [`mode`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#modes) or a [`named template`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#named-templates) instead of a making a copy.
3. The last issue is the location of the `apply-templates`. In your desired output example, you have the `BenefitEnrollment` elements being placed before `empGlobalAssignmentNav`. Where it would be output now is at the end of `EmpEmployment`. What I would suggest is matching `empGlobalAssignmentNav` instead of `EmpEmployment`. That way you can output the copy of the `BenefitEnrollment` before outputting `empGlobalAssignmentNav`.

Example:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="empGlobalAssignmentNav[EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="empGlobalAssignmentNav/EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Working fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH7UCV

If you're curious, here's another option using both mode and naming the [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying).

The benefit of this is that if I wanted to do additional processing of those `BenefitEnrollment` elements, I could remove `<xsl:call-template name="identity"/>` and do whatever processing I needed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="empGlobalAssignmentNav[EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment" mode="keep"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="BenefitEnrollment" mode="keep">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="empGlobalAssignmentNav/EmpGlobalAssignment/BenefitEnrollment"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Working fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH7UCV/1

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel, this solution has really helped